# Getting unique item from a mixed list

Tags: python

What is the best possible way to remove duplicates(get unique values) from a mixed list? This is quite achievable with a simple list as seen below using set() method:

```
trial = [['1'], ['2', '2']]
for i in trial:
    print(list(set(i)))
```

Which results to:

```
['1']
['2']
```

But with a list like the test_list variable below, the structure of the list is such that the test_list contains both list and nested list.
Using the set() method in the test_list won't work because test_list[2], test_list[3], test_list[4] are not hashable, and will throw an error.

```
test_list = [
    ['1'],
    ['2', '2'],
    [['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['5', '5'], ['6', '6']],
    [['7', '7'], ['8'], ['7'], ['1'], ['7', '7']],
    [['7', '7'], ['8'], ['7'], ['7', '7']],
    ['2', '2']]
for i in test_list:
        print(list(set(i)))
```

i get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I can't think of a logic to iterate through every element of the test_list, and eliminate every duplicate in each index, including indexes with nested list as shown below:

```
['1'] # unique values from index[0]
['2'] # unique values from index[1]
['3', '4', '5', '6'] # unique values from index[2]
['7', '8', '7', '1', '7'] # unique values from index[3]
['7', '8', '7', '7'] # unique values from index[4]
['2'] # unique values from index[5]
```

Comment: Well, that's not what this does. `set` doesn't recursively deduplicate items within items. You'll need to write code to do that if that's what you want to happen.

Comment: Because on the third iteration of your loop, *i* will refer to a list of lists - specifically *[['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['5', '5'], ['6', '6']]*

Comment: Yes, I am perfectly aware of that @- OldBill that is why I am asking if anyone knows a way to achieve such with this type of mixed list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? Like, do you know how to handle recursive data structures? You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask]. Personally, before starting work on this, I'd want to know: 1) Are the values always hashable? 2) If there can be more than one unique value in a bottom-level list, is the order important?

Comment: ... 3) Can the structure ever be mixed, like `i = ['1', ['2', '2'], '1']`, and if so, what should happen in that case? Maybe `['1', ['2']]`?

Comment: Thank you wjandrea. The order is important please. No, the structure can't be mixed. I stated the expected result in my question. I am not experienced and can't say I am fully grounded in handling recursive data.

Comment: Hi @wjandrea I have just edited the result I hope to achieve. Bare with me, i'm still getting use to asking questions here.

Answer (score -1):

Set can't process nested lists. Just use a simple loop as a workaround.

```py
arr = []
for i in [[1, 2, 3], 2, [2, 3], 2, [2, 3]]: 
  if not i in arr: arr.append(i)
```

Comment: This won't work for the type of list i have in my question. Please, take a closer look at the structure of the list if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You wish to de-dup certain things with a `set`,
but the current `list` representation is interfering with that.
Here is one thing we must be able to represent, for example:

```
[['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6']]
```

Turn it into a hashable immutable `str` with the `json` [library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> xs = [['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6']]
>>> 
>>> json.dumps(xs)
'[["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"]]'
>>>
```

Putting strings into a set is a piece of cake.
And `json.loads()` will deserialize back into a list
if that's what you need at the end of it.

You question wasn't very explicit about your app-specific
needs for pre-processing elements prior to serialing with `.dumps`,
so that part's up to you.

---

Asking whether `element in container` happens quickly
for set containers. It happens in O(1) constant time.
But for a list container it happens in O(n) linear time,
often leading to a quadratic algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get unique values in each list, when there is a **inconsistent number of nested lists**,  this is the solution:

```
def unique(lst):
    new_list = []
    for i in lst:
        if type(i) != list:
            new_list = (list(set(lst)))
            break

        else:
            new_list.append(unique(i))
    return new_list
new = unique(test_list)

print(new)
```

In your example this is the result it will give:

```
[
    ['1'],
    ['2'],
    [['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6']],
    [['7'], ['8'], ['7'], ['1'], ['7']],
    [['7'], ['8'], ['7'], ['7']], ['2']
    ]
```